# ajax complete event: match url with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, ajax, url

I'm trying to run a function after a certain ajax request is completed. 
Since there are multiple requests being made across the site, I'm filtering the one I want with `settings.url` like in the official documentation:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url === "ajax/test.html" ) {
    $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler. The result is " +
      xhr.responseText );
  }
});
```

The actual `url` looks something like this `https://example.com/page?ids=%2C1%2C2%2C`
Everything after `?ids=` is changing from request to request.

Now, the above code only fires if the `settings.url` is the exact same as in the request, id's included.

```
if ( settings.url === "https://example.com/page?ids=%2C1%2C2%2C" )
```

So I need to match `settings.url` with `https://example.com/page?ids=` and a wildcard at the end, since the id's are not important.

Would this be possible by using regex?

Comment: `if ( settings.url.indexOf("https://example.com/page?ids")  === 0) ...`

Comment: Regular expressions are the normal method of matching patterns in strings. Why wouldn't it be possible? What happened when you tried? If it didn't work, you probably just made a mistake (remember that you have to escape `/` and `?` in regular expressions). You need to post your attempt if you want help with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with regex you could take Regex to parse an URL ([What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)) and finish it off with your delimiter, in your case the =.

```
(www|http:|https:)+[^\s]+[\w]=
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let regex = /[^ ]*pageids=[^ ]*/;

if (settings.url.match(regex)) {
  console.log('triggered');
  console.log(settings.url);
}
```

It's working now. I forgot to replace `settings.url===` with `settings.url.match()`.